# How to render an html.erb partial using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am new to programming and I don't know how to go about this logic:

I have a collection select in my `events\new.html.erb` view, where a customer can select another customer:

```
#events\new.html.erb
<%= f.collection_select :id,
                                    Customer.where(business_id: current_customer.business_id),
                                    :id,
                                    :full_name,
                                    { prompt: 'Select' },
                                    { id: "colleageselect", onChange: "renderColCal(this)" } %>


            <div id = colleaguecal>

            </div>
```

When the user clicks a name, it triggers a client-side JavaScript function that creates a variable `colleagueID` which I need to use in Ruby server-side in order to retrieve the selected customer from the database

```
#application.js

function renderColCal(select){

    var colleagueID = select.value ;


    document.getElementById("colleaguecal").innerHTML = "Your colleague's calendar:";

    $.ajax({
            url: 'calendars_controller/calendarChange',
            data: (
                'colleagueID=' + $('select').val()
            )
        }
    )
}
```

The variable is picked up in Calendars#calendarChange:

```
def calendarChange
    colleagueID = params[:colleagueID]
    @colleague = Customer.where(id: :colleagueID)

    @colcalendar = @colleague.calendar
    @events = @colleague.calendar.events #sets the variables I need to use for the customer's calendar (_calendarChange.html.erb) that needs to be rendered within events\html.erb

  end
```

**How can I make it so that when the collection_select selection is changed, my `calendars\_calendarChange` is rendered within my `events\html.erb`, using the `@events` variable defined in calendars#calendarChange?**

Thanks!

EDIT:

To make it clear what I want to accomplish:

I want the customer to be able to select another customer in collection_select, and see ON THE SAME PAGE, the selected customer's calendar. This calendar requires `@events` in order to be unique to the selected customer. (each customer has their own calendar and set of events)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are trying to accomplish:

In `ruby` / `rails` world as a convention we use *snake case* naming for our methods and variable. So here `calendarChange` will become `calendar_change`.

When your function `renderColCal` gets called it will hit the `calender_change` method.

You need here to create a `calendars/calendar_change.js.erb` that will deliver `javascript` functionality as a response.

#### calendars/calendar_change.js.erb

```
// put here whatever javascript you want
// You could also use ruby code by wrapping it with erb tags
// Here an example:
$("#wrapper").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @events ) %>")
```

More infos [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html).

Comment: ok, but how do I make it so that it is rendered within events\new.html.erb? I don't want the user to be sent to a separate page, as this is just a small part of a form that they must fill out within events\new.html.erb. Is that already sorted for me? I just want it to appear within the div 'colleaguecal'

Comment: Where you say 'you need here to create calendars/calendar_change/.js.erb', do you mean by respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end

Comment: You do not need a `respond_to` `block` to get it working. Try replacing the content of `calendar_change.js.erb` with `alert('hello')` and check if it works

Comment: it gives me:  HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR): GET - http ://127.0.0.1:3000/calendars_controller/calendar_change?colleagueID=3

Comment: Did you have a route matching `calendar_change`

Comment: this is my route:  post 'calendars_controller/calendar_change', to: 'calendars_controller#calendar_change'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101329/discussion-between-marwen-and-s-craig).